# Force Close on other devices, but works on mine

Tags: android, forceclose

I'm working on an app which reads the audio files on the sd card and plays them when the start button is hit. The odd thing is that the app runs fine on my Droid RAZR, but crashes when on other devices. I have tried it on my dad's Droid RAZR and it crashes, as well as on my friends Samsung Galaxy S2, and my old Droid Incredible. I put the SD Card from my phone into my Incredible and it worked once, but I did not get the same outcome when I put it in my Dad's.

This is the code for the method with the cursor:

```
private void init_phone_music_grid() {
    System.gc();
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST }; // was originally set to MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST



    musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 65000", null, null );
    count = musiccursor.getCount(); //causes force close, when plugged in sometimes; not an issue with StateCheck class
    musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTrackList);
    musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

    musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

This is the code for the OnCreate Method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initializeVars();

    init_phone_music_grid();
    //countDown();
    trackList.setCacheColorHint(Color.GRAY);

    start.setEnabled(false);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    reset.setEnabled(false);
    trackList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    instructions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //*** USED FOR TESTING!!! ***//
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) >= 6) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setCancelable(false);
        builder1.setMessage("This test version of Musercise has ended! Buy the real one if you want to use it!");
        builder1.setPositiveButton("Close",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();
    }
    // END TESTING

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped);
            chrono.start();

            for(int i = 0; i <= trackList.getCount() - 1; i++) {
                randomArray[i] = i;
            }
            shuffleArray(randomArray);

            if(!isPaused) {
                MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(myTask, (totalTimeLong)*60000);                  
            }else if(resumeNeeded){
                MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(myTask, timeRemainingAfterPause);
                resumeNeeded = false;
                pause.setEnabled(true);
            }

            if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                music_column_index = musiccursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                musiccursor.moveToPosition(randomArray[0]);
                String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);

                    try {
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

            }

            if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                includeWarmUp.setEnabled(false);
                includeCoolDown.setEnabled(false);
                test.setEnabled(false);
                start.setEnabled(false);
                trackList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                instructions.setText("Track List:");
            }

            isPaused = false;
            drawer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.run);
        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            isPaused = true;
            resumeNeeded = true;
            timeWhenStopped = chrono.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            chrono.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.pause();

            long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chrono.getBase();
            timer.cancel();
            timeRemainingAfterPause = totalTimeLong*60000 - elapsedMillis;

            start.setEnabled(true);
            pause.setEnabled(false);

            drawer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }
    });

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            chrono.stop();
            timeWhenStopped = 0;
            chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            mMediaPlayer.reset();


            start.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            pause.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            includeWarmUp.setEnabled(true);
            includeCoolDown.setEnabled(true);
            test.setEnabled(true);
            start.setEnabled(true);
            pause.setEnabled(true);
            trackList.setEnabled(true);


            drawer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    });


    test.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
}
```

Logcat when it crashes:

```
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at com.flannigan.musercise.MuserciseActivity$3.onClick(MuserciseActivity.java:133)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-03 19:41:01.678: E/AndroidRuntime(499):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where does `musiccursor` come from? However you are getting that is what the issue is. It is coming back with no data in it on the other devices. Are you super duper certain that the correctly named file is in the correct spot on the SD card of the other devices?

Comment: @Owen2014 what you have on `MuserciseActivity.java:133`?

Comment: Okay, so I just updated the code in the original post, to include the method that includes the cursor, and I also posted all of the OnCreate Method. And PratikSharma, line 133 is the line "String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);" in the OnCreate Method. Thanks for the help btw, and @FoamyGuy, I am trying to return all of the audio files on the sd card which are over one minute long, and then I use a randomized array for the order in which they play, so that the play order is different each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this `error` :

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

which means your `cursor size` is 0 and you are trying to fetch data from `index 0`, that turns into `force close`.

**This line,**

```
String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
```

**Try to cover with this way**,

```
if(music_column_index > 0)
   String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
else
   // Toast some error message
```

Thanks.

Comment: I want to thank everyone else for the help and for their advise! I found out that the issue I was having was because I set the array size to 50, when I thought it was set to get the length of the trackList that I had. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Don't simply `moveToPosition()` on cursor , make sure cursor *can* go to that position.

Use additional checks on cursor i.e. cursor is not null, `moveToFirst()` is true , and row count lies between whatever index you supply to `moveToPosition()`.

```
if( cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0){
  int rnd = //--some random number--

  //--clamp rnd to cursor size--
  rand = Math.max(0,Math.min(cur.getCount() - 1,rnd)); 

  if(cur.moveToPosition(rnd)){
    //--do stuff--
  }

}
```

Other than that, don't get values by column index, instead, re-use the defined column names:

```
musiccursor.getString(musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
```

If its in projection then it *will* be in resulting cursor with data.